# Is there any solution for recurrence relation T(n) = T(T(n - 1)) + 1?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, recurrence

Is there any solution for this *Recurrence relation*

`T(n) = T( T( n - 1 ) ) + 1`

from code in C like syntax

```
Algo(int n)
{
    printf("%d ->",n);
    return (n >= 1)?Algo(Algo(n - 1))+1:1;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("\tEnd: %d",Algo(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Result :

**3->2->1->1->2->1->1    End: 3**

How to find Time Complexity for this relation ?

Thank you

Comment: If the base case is `T(1) = 1`, then `T(n) = n`. Proof by induction: if `T(n - 1) = n - 1`, then `T(n) = T(T(n - 1)) + 1 = T(n - 1) + 1 = n - 1 + 1 = n`.

Comment: Does it even return? Seems like an infinite recursion.

Comment: 'Time Complexity' will depend on whether u want to recurse the function.. or u want to used the simplified one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant: "return (n >= 1)?Algo(Algo(n - 1))+1:**0**"
In this case, the recursion is called exactly 2^(n + 1) - 1 times because in each stage the recursion tree splits into 2 subtrees.
You can also put a static counter and test different values of n.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any solution

Depending on the value for `T(0)`, and assuming `n = 0,1,2 ...` there is a solution :

```
T(n) = T(0) + n
```

Prove :

| n | T(n) | T(n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T(0) = | X |
| 1 | T(1) = | T(0)+1 = (X)+1 |
| 2 | T(2) = | T(1)+1 = (X+1)+1 |
| 3 | T(3) = | T(2)+1 = (X+1+1)+1 |
| 4 | T(4) = | T(3)+1 = (X+1+1+1)+1 |
| 5 | T(5) = | T(4)+1 = (X+1+1+1+1)+1 |
| 6 | T(6) = | T(5)+1 = (X+1+1+1+1+1)+1 |
| 7 | T(7) = | T(6)+1 = (X+1+1+1+1+1+1)+1 |
| 8 | T(8) = | T(7)+1 = (X+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+1 |

Please share if the solution/assumption is acceptable. ( :